# Can I automate Prettier's 'Fix all prettier/prettier problems'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

I currently have Prettier set up on VSCode to warn me when something is not correct. It's a pain to right click the underlined red to selected. 'Fix all prettier/prettier problems' all the time. I was wondering if that could be automated?

N.B. I use AutoSave on VSCode

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#--write

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Prettier to run automatically on Ctrl+S by adding these lines to your Prettier configuration file:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Please, take a look here https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#format-on-save.

Comment: That didn't work. I tried this in .prettierrrc ```{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
}
```

Comment: Try adding `"editor.formatOnSave": true` and `”[javascriptreact]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true }` or `”[typescript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true }` if you are using JSX or TypeScript. Also uninstall / install the extension and restart VSCode after making changes.